# Can a Chrome extension's event page detect when the browser has finished starting up?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that tracks the order in which tabs are accessed by listening for tab-related events like `tabs.onActivated`, `onRemoved`, etc.  It uses an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) instead of a persistent background page to add the event listeners.  The tab access order is stored in `chrome.storage.local`.

The extension works fine while in the normal course of using the browser.  But when Chrome is first launched and restores the previous session, it reopens the windows in the order they were originally opened, firing `onActivated` events for the reopened tabs.

If the extension listened to these events, they would cause the stored tab access order to change, which I'm trying to avoid.  I don't want to start listening to the tab events until Chrome has finished restoring the session and has settled down.  But I'm not sure how to detect that change in state using an event page that normally has to re-add the event listeners every time it's loaded.

I've tried something like the following to delay adding the tab event listeners until shortly after the last window has been created during startup (it listens for `windows.onCreated` because Chrome will start up in the background when you restart Windows, but no windows are created at that point):

```
var gStartingUp = false;

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
    var timer = null;

    gStartingUp = true;

    chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(window => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            gStartingUp = false;
            addListeners();
        }, 750);
    });
);

if (!gStartingUp) {
    addListeners();
}
```

In normal usage, `gStartingUp` would default to `false` and the listeners would get added.  But when the browser fires the `onStartup` event, the handler isn't called fast enough to prevent the `addListeners()` call from happening, so the listeners are added during startup as well.  I suppose I could add a timeout before calling `addListeners()`, but that would delay adding them during normal usage.

Is there a way for an extension's event page to reliably detect that Chrome has finished its startup processing?

Comment: I would use chrome.tabs.onUpdated instead of chrome.windows.onCreated in your code snippet and a smaller timer value.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid listening to `onUpdated` because it fires so often as Chrome starts up.  I'm listening to `window.onCreated` inside `onStartup` because Chrome will launch when Windows is restarted, but not open any windows.  The question is how to add all the tab listeners right away in normal usage, but not while Chrome is starting up.

Comment: I see no problem in tabs.onUpdated firing a lot with the posted code.

Comment: The issue is that the `onUpdated` handler gets the local storage, updates it with the new tab info, and then saves it back.  This can happen hundreds of times during startup if lots of tabs are reopened, and takes noticeable time, even though it's only about 25K of data.  But it sounds like the answer to the question is no, you can't reliably tell when startup is finished, so I guess I'll just have to queue the events and process them as a batch after a delay.

Comment: Like I said, use the code in the question with chrome.tabs.onUpdated. When you detect the and of startup sequence, proceed with your full-blown listeners.

Comment: I updated the code in this gist: https://gist.github.com/fwextensions/fb7d5717a100dacb50b00c9fe8f21e7b  That's fine for delaying handling until tabs have stopped updating. But then let's say the event page gets unloaded, and later `tabs.onActivated` fires. A listener had been added for that in the first `addListeners()` call, so the page is reloaded and the event handled. But in that second load, the listeners aren't re-added, since `onStartup` didn't fire again. My understanding of event pages is that it will no longer be called in that case, because it didn't re-add any listeners.

Comment: Simply unregister this temporary listener (chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener) which you can do by using a global function or any other way of storing the function reference. You don't need it anymore once the timer actually fires.

Comment: As for re-registering, see [Chrome extensions - runtime.onStartup before any other actions](//stackoverflow.com/a/33160051) Admittedly, I haven't analyzed your use case, but hopefully this can be useful.

Comment: Using an alarm might work right after the startup has finished, but my understanding is they fire at most once per minute. So wouldn't the handling of new events be delayed by at least that much?

Comment: The code I've linked doesn't use periodInMinutes, which is subject to the restriction. The documentation is just vague so try first.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but the docs say "`when` can be set to less than 1 minute after "now" without warning but won't actually cause the alarm to fire for at least 1 minute."  So that doesn't sound promising.

Comment: The docs contain mistakes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial solution below is too unreliable.  I actually saw a case where Chrome restarted, the event page loaded, the timeout to add the listeners fired after 100ms, but the `onStartup` event didn't fire for another two whole seconds.

So I gave up on trying to delay adding the event handlers until after the `onStartup` event was handled.  Instead, each handler now checks a `startingUp` flag that's set in the `onStartup` handler, and only processes the event if it's not in the startup phase.  That check is unnecessary for most of the lifetime of the extension, but it at least avoids adding an artificial delay before handling events.

I also switched to listening for `tabs.onActivated` events during startup, as Chrome seems to reopen the windows first during startup, and then reopens the tabs.  So waiting for a pause in tab activations should be a better signal that Chrome has finished starting up.

```
var startingUp = false;

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
    var timer = null;

    startingUp = true;

    function onActivated()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            startingUp = false;
            chrome.tabs.onActivated.removeListener(onActivated);
        }, 500);
    }

    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(onActivated);
);

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tabID => {
    if (!startingUp) {
        // handle event
    }
});
```

### Initial solution

The answer to that question would appear to be "no".  The best I've been able to do is indeed delay calling `addListeners()` long enough for the `onStartup` listener to fire when Chrome is starting up:

```
var startingUp = false,
    addedListeners = false;

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
    var timer = null;

    startingUp = true;

    chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(window => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            startingUp = false;
            addListeners();
        }, 500);
    });
);

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!startingUp && !addedListeners) {
        addListeners();
    }
}, 100);
```

This seems to mostly work, and the 100ms delay in adding event handlers every time the page is reloaded doesn't seem to be noticeable in actual usage (I've tried 0, 10 and 50ms delays, but they'd sometimes fire before the `onStartup` handler).

But it all feels very kludgy and brittle if the timing is off.  Any improved solutions are welcome.